# synchronizing columns on toggle in css grid

Tags: css, toggle, css-grid

I am working with columns on my webpage. I have created a very simple menu side-bar thing, in the column that is furthest to the left. In the next column is the years assigned to each project, in such a way that its perfectly aligned upon opening the webpage.

However, I've used a toggle code, so that when you click on one of the projects in the first column, a small description pops up, causing the entire column to expand vertically. This of course also means that the projects are no longer aligned with their designated year, in the following column.

I would like it so , that the numbers in the second column, would automatically align, according to the first column. How is this possible?

[image: webpage, when toggle is activated]

Here's some code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>...</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("#Project1").click(function(){
                $("p.Describtion1").toggle();
              });
            });

        </script

</head>


<body>


    <div id="content">


            <div class="FirstColumn">


                <div id="Project1">
                    Wer Baut Der Stadt 2019
                </div>

                <p class="Describtion1">
                    Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin in 2019. 
                </p>
                <br>


#content{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 18% 7% 18% 7% 18% 7% 18% 7%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, minmax(150px,auto));
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;

  text-align: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use a `<table>` for this? It seems perfect for what you are trying:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
              $("#Project1").click(function(){
                $("p.Describtion1").toggle();
              });
            });
```

```css
#content {
  width: 100%;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
#content td {
  background-color:red;
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  vertical-align: top;
}
#content td:nth-child(odd) {
  width: 18%;
}
#content td:nth-child(even) {
  width: 7%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="content">
    <tr>
        <td id="Project1">
            Wer Baut Der Stadt 2019
            <br>
            <p class="Describtion1">
            Identity and Font developed for the lecture series on architecture conducted by No Image in Berlin in 2019. 
            </p>
        </td>
        <td>2019</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="Project2">
            Hans Oscar Carlsson
        </td>
        <td>2019</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
<table>
```